# How to auto login user again after change user_login

Tags: php, database, users, sql

I have a system work by ajax that is change user_login of users and this is my code:

```
$wpdb->update($wpdb->users, array('user_login' => sanitize_text_field($args['user_login'])), array('ID' => $user_id));
```

After user_login is changed WordPress is log out this user so I try to use wp_signon after user_login changed but it's not working, Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found when attempting similar I needed to clear the user cache to get the relogin to work (after much frustrating testing!):

```
wp_cache_delete($user_id, 'users');
wp_cache_delete($old_user_login, 'userlogins'); // maybe unnecessary?
$creds = array('user_login' => $user_login, 'user_password' => $user_password, 'remember' => true);
wp_signon($creds);
```

Note for this to work you may also need the user to change their password at the same time so that you can populate the `$user_password` field with a plain text password to provide to `wp_signon`

Comment: Thank you, can I make the users enter their password instead of changing their passwords?

Comment: Since I'm not sure how/why/where you are changing the user logins, I'm not sure what to suggest... I was enabling them to change their login name via their user profile form, and enforced the change of password (and matching confirmation password) so that this could happen while remaining logged in.

Comment: I am built a social system and I am trying to make it normal like social sites like Twitter, Instagram etc.. when the user tries to change the username the user enter only his password without a need to change it.

Comment: that should be fine so long as you can check the password first then pass it as plain text to `wp_signon` then you don't need to ask them to change it (that was just my use case)

Comment: awesome, love it when that happens :-)